# How to like a facebook page from my app and which url should be used?

Tags: facebook

Well, i'm really still a newbie with facebook stuffs :)

I'm developing an application with titanium in which there is a 'like our page on facebook' button but i don't know which url to use to make user like that page , i don't even know if it's a static link or dynamic link depending on the user id for example..

On that facebook page, i tried to get the url of the like button by right clicking it and looking for the 'copy link address' option on the menu shown but that option doesn't appear on the menu.

Comment: Just put your page url, something like: `https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_NAMESPACE`

Comment: You mean that all what i can do is to open the page to be liked to the user for that he clicks himself on the page 'like' button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can use the like button go to this url: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

For example I'm creating a like button to like the coca cola page
[image]

Then if you press the get code button you will get the code necessary to  create the like button on your page, just copy and paste it